# Primitive Translation Vectors from Lattice Vectors (with varying Space Groups)

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, symmetry, space-groups, atomic-physics

I am looking at some raw POSCAR data of some Primitive Cells, and I wonder how I can get a simplified directional representation of the lattice vectors. I have two examples:

**Example 1:**

```
unknown system                          
   1.00000000000000     
     3.891768    0.000000    2.246913
     1.297256    3.669194    2.246913
     0.000000    0.000000    4.493827
   A   B
     2     1
Direct
  0.750000  0.750000  0.750000
  0.250000  0.250000  0.250000
  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

**Example 2:**

```
unknown system                          
   1.00000000000000     
    -2.015017    2.015017    2.856697
     2.015017   -2.015017    2.856697
     2.015017    2.015017   -2.856697
   P   Q   R
     2     1     1
Direct
 -0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  0.250000  0.750000  0.500000
  0.500000  0.500000 -0.000000
  0.750000  0.250000  0.500000
```

Now here's the question: For ***Example 1*** I know that the lattice can be represented by the following primitive translation vector representation:

```
     0.5    0.5    0.0
     0.0    0.5    0.5
     0.5    0.0    0.5
```

I know the above is correct because it is a basic FCC primitive cell. (Spacegroup: 225/Fm-3m | Lattice Angles: (60,60,60)).

Now I wonder what would be the relevant primitive lattice vector representation for Example 2? I just have one extra info about ***Example 2***: It is an FCC Primitive Cell (Spacegroup: 216/F-43m | Lattice Angles: (120,120,90)).

Comment: second example is not 216, it is 119/I-4m2. To change above into primitive unit cell. Type phonopy -c POSCAR --symmetry. It will generate PPOSCAR

Comment: @Pranavkumar I strongly believe that example 2 is cubic. If you compute the lattice parameters from the aforesaid lattice vectors. You will find that a=b=c.

Comment: Why don't you try spglib or phonopy(based on spglib) which detects symmetry based on all rotational symmetry. If you check symmetry with phonopy, it will also generate primitive unit cell in a file name PPOSCAR.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that does not answer my question. Also what is a PPOSCAR?

Comment: PPOSCAR is primitive unit cell of any given POSCAR. Phonopy create a POSCAR file name PPOSCAR based on underlying point symmetry.

Comment: The unit cells I have shown are primitive unit cells, how can I transform them to corresponding conventional cells?

Comment: Better to use https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109983/vasp for further discussion

Comment: @Pranavkumar that URL only leads to the chat room, but users will have to scroll up quite a lot to find where the discussion took place. [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62859517#62859517) is the link to the actual discussion. By the way Pranoy, I didn't see any response by you in the chat room, and it has also been more than 10 months since this question was asked. Did you find an answer or make progress on this issue in a different way?